# How do I reopen an account in java, using a constructor with differnt argument lengths?

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, polymorphism, args

I want to print the existing balance and name of the account, but when I put the two inside of the arguments it draws an error: args of different lengths. What will make the this.balance and this.nm appear on the form side of the program when I open an existing account?

```
public abstract class AssetAccount implements Account{
public int AcctNo;
public double balance;
public String actmsg,errmsg;
public String nm, typecd;
public double rate;
NumberFormat c = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

public AssetAccount(String typecd, String nm, double sbal) {  
   this.AcctNo = 0;
   this.actmsg = "";
   this.errmsg = "";
   this.balance= 0;
   this.typecd = typecd;

while (this.AcctNo == 0) {
        try {
            this.AcctNo = (int) (Math.random() * 1000000);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                    new FileReader(this.typecd + this.AcctNo + ".txt"));
            in.close();
            this.AcctNo = 0;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //'good' result: account does not yot exist....
            this.nm = nm;
            this.balance = sbal;
            writestatus();
            if (this.errmsg.isEmpty()) {
               actmsg = this.typecd + "Account " +
                        this.nm + " " + this.AcctNo + " opened.";
               writelog(actmsg);
            }   
            if (!this.errmsg.isEmpty()) {
                this.balance = 0;
                this.AcctNo = -1;
                this.typecd = "";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            errmsg = "Fatal error in Account constructor: " + 
                      e.getMessage();
            this.AcctNo = -1;
            this.typecd = "";
        }
    }//end of while
}//end of constructor

 public AssetAccount(String typecd, int acctno) {
     //constructor for known acct number
    errmsg = "";
    actmsg = "";
    // need to get the balance and name so that it shows when re opened
    this.typecd = typecd;
    this.AcctNo = acctno;

    try {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                            new FileReader( typecd + acctno + ".txt"));
        actmsg = this.nm + "Account " + acctno + " re-opened.";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        errmsg = "Error re-opening account: " + e.getMessage();
        this.AcctNo = -1;
    }
 }
 private void writestatus() {                                                //should write status and write log be one method?
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(
                new FileWriter(this.typecd + this.AcctNo + ".txt"));
        out.println(this.nm);
        out.println(this.balance);
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        errmsg = "Error writing status file for "
                + this.typecd + " account: "+ this.AcctNo;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        errmsg = "General error in status update: " + e.getMessage();
    }
} //end of writestatus
```

Comment: catch (IOException e) { "this is not right place to put your code"}

Comment: It is not clear to me what the problem is. It would help to post [mcve].  For example: if one constructor is not relevant to the question, remove it.